# Searching mapped list to return higher values

Tags: scala, list

My current system can find the last value of a list of integers, shown in the first file below. Then it displays this as the "Current" value. I need to be able to find all of the "Current" values when I enter a search and return all of the results higher than the one I searched for.The list is saved as a Map(String, List[Int]).

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
SK6, 2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9
SK7, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0
SK8, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6
SK9, 7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6
```

This is what I am trying to get; using the data file from above, If I searched for "SK5" the system would return;

Figures higher than SK5 - 3

SK4 - 8

SK6 - 9

SK8 - 6

SK9 - 6

Here is my current code to find the last number in the list

```
  //5 - Show Current Stock Level (W)
  def handleFive(): Boolean = {
    mnuShowSingleDataStock(currentStockLevel)
    true
  }

// Returns a single result, not a list
  def mnuShowSingleDataStock(stock: (String) => (String,Int)) = {
    print("Stock > ")
    val data = stock(readLine)
    println(s"${data._1}: ${data._2}")
  }

  //Show higher than stocks
  def higherThan(stock: String): List[(String, List[Int])] = {
    mapdata.toList.sortWith(_._2.last > _._2.last).takeWhile(row => row._2.last > mapdata.get(stock).map(_.last).getOrElse(0))
  }
```

Comment: What do mean by figures higher than `SK5` and what is of `- 3` in `SK5 - 3`

Comment: @pamu As I said in my question, the value "- 3" is the "Current" value of SK5, this is the last element in the list. So by figures higher than, I am referring to all the other "Current" values, so the last elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Sort based on the last value and then take while current stock value is greater than the searched stock value

```
def higherThan(stock: String): List[(String, List[Int])] = {
  mapdata.toList.sortWith(_._2.last > _._2.last).takeWhile(row => row._2.last > mapdata.get(stock).map(_.last).getOrElse(0))
}
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my question, I have made the changes but I am getting another error using your answer. I have currently been using "String, List(Int)", you however use list, string, list, int

Comment: @AndreQueen corrected the answer. Please check...Parenthesis missing in return type of the function `List[(String, List[Int])]`

Comment: Thats great, that works fine now, im having trouble selecting the number to search for, in my answer i have added the error. The search function itself seems to be getting errors with the new function @pamu